# Consults and counts in multiple databases

Tags: mysql, subquery, syntax

I'm not very familiar with mysql advanced queries, because I'm more of a designer as a developer.
My problem - I have 3 tables:

```
Clients

------------------------------------------------------
| id |        name        |          email           |
------------------------------------------------------ 
| 1  | Client 1           | client1@somecompany.com  |
| 2  | Client 2           | client2@somecompany.com  |
| 3  | Client 3           | client3@somecompany.com  |
| 4  | Client 4           | client4@somecompany.com  |
| 5  | Client 5           | client5@somecompany.com  |
| 6  | Client 6           | client6@somecompany.com  |
| 7  | Client 7           | client7@somecompany.com  |
| 8  | Client 8           | client8@somecompany.com  |
| 9  | Client 9           | client9@somecompany.com  |
| 10 | Client 10          | client10@somecompany.com |
------------------------------------------------------


Products
--------------------------------
| id | client_id |  item_name  |
--------------------------------
| 1  | 6         |  something  |
| 2  | 4         |  something  |
| 3  | 6         |  something  |
| 4  | 2         |  something  |
| 5  | 5         |  something  |
| 6  | 7         |  something  |
| 7  | 9         |  something  |
| 8  | 10        |  something  |
| 9  | 1         |  something  |
| 10 | 5         |  something  |
| 11 | 8         |  something  |
--------------------------------

product_status

------------------------------
| id | product_id |  status  |
------------------------------
| 1  | 1          | new      |
| 2  | 2          | used     |
| 3  | 3          | new      |
| 4  | 4          | used     |
| 5  | 5          | used     |
| 6  | 6          | new      |
| 7  | 7          | used     |
| 8  | 8          | used     |
| 9  | 9          | new      |
| 10 | 10         | used     |
| 11 | 11         | new      |
------------------------------
```

I need know the following:

- Id and name of client
- How many items has the client
- How many items "new" and "used"

Like this

```
expected results
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| client_id | client_name | total_items | Items_new | Item_used |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | Client 1    | 1           | 1         | 0         |
| 2         | Client 2    | 1           | 0         | 1         |
| 3         | Client 3    | 1           | 0         | 1         |
| 4         | Client 4    | 1           | 0         | 1         |
| 5         | Client 5    | 1           | 0         | 1         |
| 6         | Client 6    | 2           | 2         | 0         |
| 7         | Client 7    | 1           | 0         | 1         |
| 8         | Client 8    | 1           | 1         | 0         |
| 9         | Client 9    | 1           | 0         | 1         |
| 10        | Client 10   | 1           | 0         | 1         |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do I know which product_id belongs to which client_id?

Comment: in the table "products", any product has a client_id field. So, the relation are in that table.

Comment: How to decide whether an item is new or used?

Comment: the system charges the product status in the third table: "product_status"

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables and then use (conditional) aggregation.

```
SELECT c.id client_id,
       c.name client_name,
       count(p.id) total_items,
       count(CASE
               WHEN ps.status = 'new'
                 1
             END) items_new,
       count(CASE
               WHEN ps.status = 'used'
                 1
             END) items_used
       FROM clients c
            LEFT JOIN products p
                      ON p.client_id = c.id
            LEFT JOIN product_status ps
                      ON ps.product_id = p.id
       GROUP BY c.id,
                c.name;
```

This shows data for all clients. If you only want them actually having a product, you need to change the first `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

It also counts products which have no status in `items`. If you don't want to include such products, change the second `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` as well.